# How to send FireBase custom push notification from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I send custom push notification from c#?
I have seen in the firebase console, there's an advance options to send custom data as key value pairs. I want to send key value pairs in c#.
Any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To send push notifications programmatically, have a look at the [Firebase Cloud Messaging API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server). The best starting points is to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) either in your existing Node.js environment, or in Cloud Functions as shown in [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).